# Using pyinstaller to make standalone file on Mac

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, pyinstaller

I'm trying to use pyinstaller with python version 2.7 to make a standalone file that will run a small app I made using tkinter, but I'm having trouble following the documentation. I found [this](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/08/10/a-pyinstaller-tutorial-build-a-binary-series/), but it's for python 2.5 and windows

http://www.pyinstaller.org/export/v2.0/project/doc/Manual.html?format=raw#spec-files

I made two folders on my desktop, one for pyinstaller and one containing my files.

In terminal I changed the directory to the pyinstaller folder. Then I typed the following:

```
python pyinstaller.py /Users/.../Desktop/BuildFolder/menu.py
//buildfolder contains my files, menu.py is the file I run to start the app
```

When this runs, I get a message staing something along the lines of "The output directory and all of its contents will be removed. Proceed y/n?" Upon selecing yes, It then creates the directory

```
/Users/.../Desktop/pyinstaller-2.0/menu
```

Inside that menu folder, there's a .SPEC file. So, I run the following in terminal

```
python pyinstaller.py /Users/.../Desktop/BuildFolder/menu/menu.spec
```

After this runs, I found a .PKG file in that folder but it's not labeled anything like menu.py . I can't figure out what to do next, and I'm not sure if I'm supposed to run other files.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure ( haven't tried this yet ), but maybe you have to run Build.py while working with .SPEC file?